# UITableViewController scrollToRowAtIndexPath UI issue with quicktype keyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield, overlap, quicktype

I have a `UITableViewController` with custom cells that have text fields in them. I want the table view to scroll whenever the user enters a text field, so I do this:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{
    // ... irrelevant code here ...

    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

    // ... more irrelevant code here ...
}
```

This method normally works great, but when quicktype keyboard appears the quicktype bar partially overlaps the cell.

How do I fix that overlapping issue?

Comment: If you do not need quick type keyboard then you can use `textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo`. If you need it, why don't you scroll to row next to targeted one.

Comment: I kind of don't want to get rid of the quick type keyboard, unless there's just no other way. I was hoping there are cleaner solutions than just scrolling to the cell below. Also, what happens when you want to edit the last cell?